# Solving PDEs given by a vector field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

> I have a non-compact smooth manifold $M$, a compactly supported smooth vector field $X$ on $M$ and a compactly supported smooth function $f$ on $M$.
>
> Does there exist a compactly supported smooth function $F$ on $M$ such that $(dF)(X) = f$?

I thought about integrating $f$ along the integral curves of $X$ to get $F$. Does this actually always work or do I miss something (some nasty special cases which might occur)?

Comment: There are some conditions to satisfies (at least when $X$ is not of compact support): For example if $M=\mathbb R$ and $X = e_1$. Then as $dF(X) = F'$, $\int_a^b dF(X) dt = 0$, so $f$ should satisfy $\int f(x) dx = 0$.